# Assign a variable to the next item in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, allocation

I am having trouble assigning a user entered variable to the "next" variable in a linked list. (ie head->next->num = sum) Normally enclosing the node in parenthesis works to assign a variable to one of the items in the list but i can't seem to apply the same logic to the next item in the list. I'm unsure if it's a syntax issue or allocation but it keeps seg faulting. Code example below of what i'm talking about.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct fib {
  long long num;

  struct fib *next;

} fib;
typedef void (*callback)(fib *point);
char menu();
void welcome();
void help();
void exitmssg();
void print(fib *head, callback f);
void display(fib *n);
fib *run(fib *head, int count);

void main() {
  long long num1, num2, sum;
  int count;
  callback disp = display;
  fib *head, *pointer, *append;
  welcome();
  head = malloc(sizeof(fib));
  pointer = malloc(sizeof(fib));
  printf("Please enter two starting fibonacci numbers:\n");
  scanf("%lli", &num1);
  scanf("%lli", &num2);
  (head->num) = num1;
  (head->next->num) = num2;
//((head->next)->num) doesn't work either
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use an uninitialized pointer. `head->next` is not initialized.

```
head = malloc(sizeof(fib));
pointer = malloc(sizeof(fib));
head->num = num1;
head->next = pointer;      // Now next points to something
head->next->num = num2;
pointer->next = NULL;      // This needs initialization too
```

And it's not a syntax error - it's a runtime error. If it was a syntax error, the compiler would tell you and it wouldn't compile/run.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/7jLz8w)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize you have to allocate head->next as well, but that makes perfect sense. Then in the assignment line, how do you reference the "num" of head->next?  ie (head->next->num) = num2

Comment: `head->next->num` is correct. There must be an error elsewhere. https://ideone.com/7jLz8w

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation... I think I was being a bit dense!  lol